# What is the origin of the probability interpretation of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Born came up with his probability interpretation of quantum mechanics. But why did he think about such an interoretation? Why not thinking that a deterministic process has to lay at its foundation? All known processes were known to be fundamentally deterministic. A dice thrown, the motion of the stars, the motions of atoms in a macroscopic gas, etc. Why did he think that the processes in QM are inherently probabilistic? A notion hard to digest (you can say QM is hard to digest but this begs the question).

Comment: A very entertaining and accessible book on this is [**Thirty Years that Shook Physics: The Story of Quantum Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/048624895X) by George Gamow.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I prefer the paperback. 12 dollar. Hardback, only 902 dollars... only one left in stock...

Comment: I have both, the hardback being purchased around 35 to 40 years ago (used, for probably around \$2 to \$3), and the paperback revised edition being purchased around 10 to 12 years ago (at another used bookstore, purchased because it was basically in new condition for about \$6 or \$7, and I'd forgotten I had the hardback -- I had read a library hardback copy in the mid 1970s and thus the hardback copy I purchased wound up being shuffled from box to box  and forgotten during my frequent moves in the 1980s, 1990s, and 2000s).

Comment: @DaveLRenfo Did you buy it for that low price? Why is it so expensive now? I think if you have a first edition it will be worth a bit more...

Comment: This is almost certainly a feedback artifact of [algorithmic pricing](https://www.wired.com/2011/04/amazon-flies-24-million/). If you really want a book that seems impossibly high-priced at amazon, look for it at various other booksellers -- I usually just google the book's title and author and the phrase "used book", or something similar, and then look at the non-amazon google hits.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Im gonna buy the paperback. At the same time Im gonna look how the hardcover price develops. Interesting!

Comment: @Nick As I mentioned in my question. But why?  It seems like the east way out.

Comment: Even if a deterministic process is at the "foundation" a physical equation (Schrödinger's, in this case) can still be probabilistically interpreted. Boltzmann demostrated that with statistical mechanics, and Einstein, who was [Born's inspiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule#History), applied it to Brownian motion and photoeffect. Besides, by that time Schrödinger already tried to give a classical field interpretation to his equation, unsuccessfully, and earlier [BKS theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BKS_theory) postulated that even conservation laws were merely statistical.

Comment: @Conifold Still, a probabilistic interpretation is different from a deterministic substrate as Bolzmann proved.

Comment: Born needed an interpretation to convert Schrödinger's solutions into predictions. Plain field interpretations of the wave function were shown to be non-sensical, and the "substrate" at the "foundation" was moot.

Comment: @Conifold Moot indeed. And thus meaningfull.